# How to serve static folders using Chi router

Tags: go, go-chi

I want to serve a folder that has the next form:

```
my-project/
  - public/ <- The folder that I want to serve and also all the subfolders and files
    - css/
      - styles.css

    - js/
      - script.js

  - main.go
```

And I want to visit it with the URL's `http://localhost/api/static/css/styles.css` and `http://localhost/api/static/js/script.js`

So I tried to do the next:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5"
)

func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()

    r.Handle("/api/static/*", http.StripPrefix("/public/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./public"))))

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":80", r); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

This not works, it gives me an HTTP 404 error code when I try to visit either `http://localhost/api/static/css/styles.css` or `http://localhost/api/static/js/script.js`

Comment: Strip /api/static, not /public

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to strip `/api/static` from the path, so, for instance, if a request comes for `/api/static/css/styles.css`, stripping it will leave `css/styles.css`, which will be looked up under `./public` to give `./public/css/styles.css`.